# Why byte's representation differs when initialized directly than initializing by make?

Tags: go

https://golang.org/src/go/types/type.go?s=485:503#L10 states that `byte` is an alias for `uint8` and `rune` is an alias for `int32`

When I execute the following code block I receive the following output

```
b1, b2 := [1]byte{}, make([]byte, 1)
fmt.Printf("b1: %#v, b2: %#v", b1, b2)
```

```
Output: b1: [1]uint8{0x0}, b2: []byte{0x0} // I'm trying to make sense of this inconsistency
```

```
r1, r2 := [1]rune{}, make([]rune, 1)
fmt.Printf("r1: %#v, r2: %#v", r1, r2)
```

```
Output: b1: [1]int32{0x0}, b2: []int32{0x0} // go's representation consistent here
```

But the difference shown here for `byte` is not there for `rune` which is an alias as well.

What could be the reason for this representation difference for `byte` between `make` and direct initialization?

Comment: I made a program in the go playground so we can explore this issue: https://play.golang.org/p/hQApiZ12fSF  It prints out 8 variables.  Which specific ones are you confused about, and why?  Do you know the difference between a slice and an array?

Comment: Yes I know the difference and I'm aware the first definition is an array and make returns a  slice that points to the underlying array. The output already makes that clear by printing `[1]type`, but I didn't understand the reason for array `byte` alias  `uint8` shown and for slice `byte` `byte` shown, but this is not the case for rune, what makes the difference?

Comment: The functions in fmt do too much magic you have to be aware of to use them to "understand" language internals. Fortunately language internals in Go are  dead simple. Just read the language spec which is astonishingly accessible (and short).

Answer (score 1):

2 reasons. One those values are not the same

- `[1]byte{}` is a byte **array** of length 1
- `make([]byte, 1)` is a byte **slice** of length 1

In the implementation of `fmt`, a byte slice (`[]byte`) is a handled special case, a byte **array** is not. So the aliasing for a byte **slice**is handled. A rune slice or array are not cases, and therefore are shown as the underlying type vs the alias.  See the switch statement for types:

https://github.com/golang/go/blob/076a45acd5b8d2ce08a2dbe898dc9228554db92d/src/fmt/print.go#L696

---

An equivalent to `make([]byte, 1)` is `[]byte{0x00}`.

https://play.golang.org/p/k8DiFoy4mNl

Comment: Very interesting, I actually looked at the spot with blame, the commit message exactly spots on the difference on `%#v` output  but if I'm not mistaken the bug is still there 
```Add tests that make sure we do not accidentally alter the
behavior of printing []byte for []byte and []uint8 type
if they are used at the top level when formatting with %#v.```
https://github.com/golang/go/commit/9149aa10cc2f7d3061303754ab45c55eff42ac89

Comment: Oh that is a neat find. I guess they are locked into this behavior now